# iOS: seems like glDeleteBuffers not freeing the memory

Tags: ios, c, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL ES buffers in various places (Texture, Index, Color buffers, etc).

When I am profiling my OpenGL ES code with Allocations, I see that all `glBufferData` memory stored in GL context is never freed.

It is listed in Allocations utility under 
`allocateWCMemory` in the library `GLEngine`.

Profiling was performed on iPad Mini 2 with iOS 8.3 (OpenGL ES 3.0).

After numerous usages of glBufferData (always with different buffers, only once per buffer) no single allocation has been freed by glDeleteBuffers.

glDeleteBuffers is called for all generated buffers after they aren't needed.

Is there something else on GL ES 3.0 that I have to do with that additionally to free the buffers? What are alternatives to glBufferData if it is a system issue of `GLEngine` iOS implementation?

Comment: The driver is allowed to delay actual deletion, instead consider a reuse strategy for the buffers.

Comment: If it does that, then it does that not smart enough because it is not freeing any buffers after 20-30 reopenings of my OpenGL scene, and finally not reacting on memory warnings until app is terminated due to memory pressure.

Comment: My OpenGL scene is represented modally and is a small part of the app functionality, but user can represent it as many times as he needs. So, basically, after it is dismissed, no buffers are needed, and they must be deleted. But they apparently aren't.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I have the exact same problem

Comment: I did not find a solution, it's an iOS system issue. Maybe I will create an Apple radar one day when I will turn back to it.